# Make a div fill the remaining height of the browser window without javascript

Tags: html, css

First I want to show the layout to you, so I think it will be clear what I try to achieve:

[image]

The first div is on the top of the page and has a static height. The second div has to fill the remaining space to the bottom. How can i achieve this without javascript or jQuery?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [`calc()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#calc-notation) function to do this.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#top {
  background: #00A743;
  height: 100px;
}
#bottom {
  background: #40008B;
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
}
```

```html
<div id="top"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Comment: How compatible is this?

Answer (score 2):

Compatible on all the browsers

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.head {
  height: 100px;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #00963F;
  position: absolute;
  border-width: 5px 5px 0 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.cont {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: #27338B;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: white;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">Fixed height</div>
<div class="cont">Rest of the browser height</div>
```

Comment: Which parts of the CSS are the essential ones for solving the stated problem? Obviously some are to make the results obvious or pretty. But to us newbies it's hard to be 100% certain which lines fall into which category.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this.

```
#div1 
{
    position:absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: #900;
}

#div2
{
    position:absolute;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    top: 200px;
    background-color: #090;
}
```